# Bash Terminal about ttysxxx

Tags: macos, bash

I just open two separated Terminal windows, and one is ttys000, the other is ttys001. I typed the command on the ttys000 window;

```
$ echo "Test" > /dev/ttys001
```

and then show up the info that "Permission denied". So I turn in the root and want to do it again like above command, but it says "Operation not supported"...

I thought the ttys001 window should show the "Test" string.

Why this happen?

Comment: sorry, MIstyped...   Actually it is ttys001.   But still not work.... Could you try it?

Comment: It works for me. Hm.. I'm not using OSX. .... And that reminds me, sorry ... This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate on the related site http://apple.stackexchange.com (AskDifferently). Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Shellter!  I am a fresher on this platform and I will follow your suggestion. Thanks again for your guide.